# Transcribe Streams of Audio Data in Real-Time with Python

Tags: python, django, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I developed a web app using Django as a backend and a Frontend library.

I have used django-channels, for WebSocket and I am able to record the audio stream from the front end and send it to Django over WebSocket and then Django sends it to the group.

So I'm able to do live audio calls (let's say) but I have to transcribe the audio at the backend. (the main goal of the project)

I'm looking forward to using [SpeechRecognition 3.8.1](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) package to achieve transcription.

I send **base64** encoded **opus** codecs string from the front end to Django every second. It sends microphone recorded audio every 1 second.

My doubts -

If we play Audio streams independently, we are only able to play the first string. We are not able to play 2nd, 3rd .... independently (padding issues or maybe more I'm not aware of), so I have used [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) at front end to buffer the streams and play. The question is can we convert this 2nd 3rd audio stream into text using the above-mentioned package? or I will have to do something else. (I'm looking for ideas here on how will this work)

Also, the above-mentioned package uses a wav format to transcribe audio, so how can I convert my base64 encoded string into a wav format audio file on the go? I have seen many examples of people using files but  I'm looking to change the audio format on the go and then save the transcribed data to a file/database.

Will provide any code example required to better understand the question.

Also, open to new ideas to change my working code workflow to achieve transcription.

Thanks !!

Comment: I have solved this issue, if anyone is looking for a solution can comment here.

Comment: Yes, looking for a solution as well.

Comment: @Satish may I know what actual solution you are looking for?

Comment: Looking for a Django based webapp, that can transcribe audio stream via WebSocket. I am looking to interface with an external api to send chunks of audio stream (5 secs) or so to an external transcriber provider as well.

Comment: When I was trying to build this I found [app link](https://blog.deepgram.com/live-transcription-django/) , you can send your audio stream via WebSocket and achieve transcription.

Comment: what I have done is for every new audio call, I created a new session, (coz first chunk of data is very important and then we can concat remaining chunks) and I store chunks  in database, (i send base64 encoded data from frontend to django). And when the user needs to transcribe later I convert to wav file and use the SpeechRecognition package to transcribe the complete wav file, my solution is not real time but can be achieved by doing few more modifications.

Comment: @RanuVijay could you please post your solution here as an answer?